# How to create QQuickWindow as a child from a C++ extended QQuickItem?

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qtquick2

This question is motivated by the following QML:

```
ApplicationWindow {
    Rectangle {
        Text { text: "Hello World" }
    }

    Item {
        // I do something

        Window {
            Text { text: "Hello world too!" }
        }
    }
}
```

In this example, there is an application window and then a second window inside of an item. I'm trying to replicate this usage, but by instantiating a `QQuickWindow` inside of an extended `QQuickItem`, but as per the documentation I can't as `QQuickItem` is not of type `QWindow`. What I would like is this:

```
class Foo : public QQuickItem {
private:
    QQuickWindow * childWindow;
public:
    Foo(QQuickItem * parent = 0) : QQuickItem(parent) {
        childWindow = new QQuickWindow();
        childWindow->setParent(this);
        // Add custom items to childWindow
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, again, this fails at the `childWindow->setParent(this)`, since `QQuickItem` does not extend `QWindow`. How could I do this in a similar fashion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Window`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-window-window.html) is not the child of the item and of any element that is easy to see with the following code:

```
ApplicationWindow {
    width: 100
    height: 100
    visible: true
    Rectangle {
        Text { text: "Hello World" }
    }

    Item{
        id: item
        Window{
            id: new_window
            visible: true
            color: "red"
            Component.onCompleted: console.log("new_window :",new_window.parent)
        }
        Component.onCompleted: console.log("item :", item.parent)
    }
}
```

Output:

```
qml: item : ContentItem_QMLTYPE_10(0x56353791dbe0)
qml: new_window : undefined
```

Clearly it is seen that the [`Item`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-item.html) is a child of the [`contentItem`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-applicationwindow.html#contentItem-prop), on the other hand [`Window`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-window-window.html) has no parent.

Comment: Oh, so I should just be able to instantiate without setting a parent?

Comment: @iHowell yes, but change `childWindow = new QQuickItem();` to `childWindow = new QQuickWindow();` and add `childWindow->show()`. Finally, it is your task to eliminate it from memory.

Comment: Wish I could upvote this twice, saved a lot of headache time.